# Rebuild auto-complete index (or whatever it's called) and binaries in $PATH cache in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

After installing new software, an already opened terminal with zsh won't know about the new commands and cannot generate auto-complete for those. Apparently opening a new terminal fix the problem, but can the index (or whatever you call it) be rebuilt so that auto-complete will work on the old terminal?

I tried with `compinit` but that didn't help. Also, is there a way that is not shell-dependent? It's nice to have a way to verify the answer as well (except for uninstalling something and reinstalling it).

What I mean is after typing a few characters of a command's name, I can press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and `zsh` should do the rest to pull up the full name.

Comment: There are two types of auto-completion you could mean when you say that an existing shell “cannot generate auto-complete for [the new commands]”:

“command completion”—trying to get the shell to suggest the new command’s name when completing in the command position, and “argument completion”—trying to get the shell to suggest options/arguments for the new command once you have already typed its name.

Which is giving you problems?

Comment: Good question! I'd always just assumed it couldn't be done, I didn't think to check

Comment: offtopic - people are so fickle 4 people favorited but only 2 upvote... I find it odd how few people upvote things.

Comment: @Chris I mean after typing a few characters of a command's name and press tab, zsh should do the rest and pull up the full name.

Comment: @xeno I noticed that too; it's pretty unusual to favorite something but not upvote it

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To rebuild the cache of executable commands, use `rehash` or `hash -rf`.

Make sure you haven't unset the `hash_list_all` option (it causes even fewer disk accesses but makes the cache update less often).

If you don't want to have to type a command, you can tell zsh not to trust its cache when completing by putting the following line in your `~/.zshrc`¹:

```
zstyle ":completion:*:commands" rehash 1
```

There is a performance cost, but it is negligible on a typical desktop setting today. (It isn't if you have `$PATH` on NFS, or a RAM-starved system.)

The `zstyle` command itself is documented in the `zshmodule` man page. The styles values are documented in the `zshcompsys` and `zshcompwid` man pages, or you can read the source (here, of the `_command_names` function). If you wanted some readable documentation… if you find some, let me know!

¹  <sub>requires zsh≥4.3.3, thanks [Chris Johnsen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1107/chris-johnsen)</sub>

Comment: Either rehash incantation should enable command-name completion of “new commands” in shells that were previously fully hashed. Setting PATH (or path) will also cause a rehash; thus  `PATH="$PATH"` would also do the job.

`HASH_LIST_ALL` is shown as a default in my documentation.

Comment: That's the answer for me.

Comment: I have zsh 5.8 and the `zstyle` command does not work for me upon modifying a completion file.

Comment: After installing package "some-cmd", `hash -r` makes the _command_ name completable, but its parameter completions are still missing, despite being added together with the (brew/deb/apk/...) package. The only way I can make it happen is to exit the shell and start a new session.

Comment: @conny Indeed neither bash nor zsh detects newly added command completions on the fly. You can run `exec zsh` (or `exec bash` as applicable) to completely reload the shell configuration, but keep the terminal and environment. Exactly what this does to your history (keep recent entries in the same order, or merge in the history from other terminals) depends on the shell configuration.

Answer (score 17):

If you are having problems getting “argument completion” working for the new commands then *compinit* is probably the command you need, however it has a caching mechanism that might be causing your problem.

The documentation for my version (4.3.10) says that *compinit* uses a cached “dump file”, `.zcompdump`, to store compiled completion functions to speed up subsequent invocations. It only invalidates the dump file when it notices a change in the number of completion files (`fpath` element files that start with `#compdef …` or `#autoload …`). Presumably installing new software would change the number of such completion files (assuming that it also installed its *zsh* auto-complete files in the right place), so I would expect a plain `compinit` to work. If you are in a situation where it does not work you may need to bypass or manually invalidate the dump file.

To skip using the dump file, use `compinit -D`; this will only affect the current shell.

To rebuild the dump file, remove it and rerun `compinit`:

```
rm -i ${ZDOTDIR:-${HOME:?No ZDOTDIR or HOME}}/.zcompdump &&
compinit
```

This will affect the current shell, existing shells that run plain `compinit`, and any future shells.

Comment: Some zsh frameworks like `zim` allow the use of per-host dump files. In that case, also remove `$zcompdump_file` together with `.zcompdump`.

Answer (score 9):

I have found that when dealing with/developing completions that live in a file with a `#compdef _foo foo` that I need to use upon each edit:

```
unfunction _foo && compinit
```

in order to see the updated `foo` command completing with the updated changes.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!