# zsh autcomplete not updating path executables

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rebuild auto-complete index (or whatever it's called)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/rebuild-auto-complete-index-or-whatever-its-called)

After I install something via aptitude, zsh won't be able to find it until I search for it with `which`. For example

```
~ sudo apt-get install xsane
~ xsa<Tab>
~ saned
~ which xsane
/usr/bin/xsane
~xsa<Tab>
~xsane
```

This naturally is pretty annoying. Is there a zsh setting for this? Or is it a bug? Or what?

Comment: @Maciej: This isn't quite the same question: the other question is about rebuilding the cache manually, this one is about doing it automatically.

Comment: @Gilles I think the answers are probably the same though (and your accepted answer on the other question covers this already)

Comment: You can tell zsh not to trust its cache when completing with `zstyle ":completion:*:commands" rehash 1`. There is a performance cost, but it is negligible on a typical desktop setting today. (It isn't if you have `$PATH` on NFS, or a RAM-starved system.) For a one-time need, run `rehash` to rebuild the command cache.

Comment: @Michael: I don't think my answer on the other command covers Falmarri's question. I was in the process of writing one (see previous comment) when the closed question notice came.

Comment: @Gilles Oh, `hash_list_all` isn't it? Well, I'll reopen this; if it is a dupe it can always be closed again and merged

Comment: Hmm "After installing new software, an already opened terminal with zsh won't know about the new commands, and cannot generate auto-complete for those" vs. "After I install something via aptitude, zsh won't be able to find it until I search for it with which" sounds rather similar. Could anyone explain what is the difference - both are about autocompletion problem after something was installed.

Comment: Well I tried the `hash_list_all` and it didn't work. I'm seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: Gilles’ comment/answer of `zstyle ":completion:*:commands" rehash 1` works in Zsh 4.3.3 and later.

Comment: @Maciej, @Michael: now that I've slept on it, I agree with the merge. Sorry about that. I'll either make my comment into an answer here or merge it into my answer there tonight.